# Error Code 1136 En Sql ayuda

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un error en mi codigo y no puedo ver que que falla, ya revise varias veces y no encuentro problemas.

El error dice:

```
insert into Salas values (09, 'Pesas', 'Primer piso', 100)  Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

El problema es con un insert:

```
create table Salas
(
    numero_sala int (3)  primary key,
    tipo_sala varchar(45) not null,
    ubicacion varchar(45),
    m2 int(3)
);
```

y el insert es

```
insert into Salas values (09, 'Pesas', 'Primer piso', 100);
insert into Salas values (05, 'Caminadora', 'Segundo piso', 100);
insert into Salas values (06, 'Estiramiento' ,'Segundo piso', 100);
```

Comment: ¿Qué sentencia genera el error? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: 0 2 10:48:24 insert into Salas values ('Pesas', 'Primer piso', 100) Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 0.000 sec @jachguate

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye esa información allí. Creo que el mensaje de error es claro, la sentencia `insert` no es como la que publicas en la pregunta, le falta el primer campo (el `numero_sala`).

Comment: Hice pruebas con tu código para crear la tabla y los tres insert que colocas en tu pregunta, pero no obtuve el error que presentas. como construyes los insert? estas trabajando directamente en el gestor de base de datos o con un lenguaje de programación?

Comment: @Arreguin92 pues, trabajo con wampserver y my sql, pero no se si es problema de mi compu

Comment: @ErikAlcantara Seria muy raro que fuese un problema con tu equipo, pero te comento, a grandes rasgos ese error se debe a que el numero de los argumentos de tu insert no coincide con el numero de los campos de tu tabla. Pero en los códigos que nos pones en tu pregunta no hay ese error

Comment: Te recomiendo como buena práctica siempre que hagas un `insert` declares las columnas. Por ej: `insert into Salas (numero_sala,  tipo_sala, ubicacion, m2) values (09, 'Pesas', 'Primer piso', 100);`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias por el consejo lo aplicare :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta crear la tabla sin ponerle limite de caracteres en el int, a mi me funciono y me dejo hacer el insert usando tu codigo

```
create table Salas
(
    numero_sala int primary key,
    tipo_sala varchar(45) not null,
    ubicacion varchar(45),
    m2 int
);
```